# Disable warning log in boost::ublas

Tags: c++, boost, boost-ublas

While inverting a matrix with `boost::ublas` I sometimes get this error in the log:

> Check failed in file /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/lu.hpp at line
>   298: detail::expression_type_check (prod
>   (triangular_adaptor (m), e), cm2)

I am aware this is generally useful information, but not in my case. Is there any way to suppress that message (somehow configuring boost, or using a compiler flag)? `BOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG` doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at that header reveals:

```
#if BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK
        BOOST_UBLAS_CHECK (detail::expression_type_check (prod (triangular_adaptor<const_matrix_type, upper> (m), e), cm2), internal_logic ());
#endif
```

It's even [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/options.html):

> #### BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK
>
> When BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK is enabled then all possibly expensive structure checks are enabled. If this is not desireable then use `#define BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK 0` before including any uBLAS header. The define BOOST_UBLAS_TYPE_CHECK_EPSILON can be used to control the acceptable tolerance, see `detail/matrix_assign.hpp` for implementation details of this check.